# Microsoft Teams, Fetch ALL chat messages with MS Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I need to fetch all of the users' chats (even private ones) since the Admin had already given us their consent.

How can I do that using Graph API?

We are a bit confused between the Delegated vs. Application Permissions `(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)`.

I am calling the `/users/< user-id >/chats` for a **user-id** different from mine (I am the admin) but it returs that the call is **unauthorized**

Can the Admin get Delegated Permissions through setting their org-wide policies appropriately?

Comment: I think there is a bug in the api documentation. If you call the `/users` endpoint, you should grant application permissions, and then use the client credential flow without user interaction to obtain an access token, but the documentation says that application permissions are not supported, so I think this is a bug.

Comment: @CarlZhao can you be more specific?

Comment: Refer to my answer.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @CarlZhao accepted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, you can only call the `/me` endpoint to get the chat message of the logged-in user, but you cannot call the `/users` endpoint to get the chat message of other users.

The `/users` endpoint usually has no user interaction, that is, no user is logged in. This endpoint requires **application permissions**, and then uses a daemon-based [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token. But the api documentation clearly states that application permissions are not supported, but it also lists the `/users` endpoint, which is contradictory, so I think this is a bug.

Of course, you can also use `/users/< user-id >/chats` to get chat message, but you can only use the id of the logged-in user, not the id of other users. But it doesn’t make sense, because this is the same as calling the `/me` endpoint no difference.

Comment: That's what I was thinking also, so what you are telling me is that either there is an error in API documentation (the note that application permissions are not premited) or there is a bug in API structure, that could possibly could mean that we can not fetch the users chat messages.

Comment: @chatzich  Yes, this is exactly what I want to say. Therefore, I suggest that you [create a support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and submit the bug to Microsoft.  Alternatively, you can also submit a [feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) and I will vote on it.

Comment: I have created a support request already.
Are you proposing me to ask for admin API chat access to users messages?

Comment: DONE! https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42759071-microsoft-teams-fetch-all-chat-messages-with-ms-g

Comment: I already voted for you:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSqtE.png

Comment: Thank you Carl I am trying to add you at LinkedIn but there are several persons with your name!

Comment: @chatzich  I used another account to log in, my name is: `frank`. My account is: `gongjiubao@outlook.com`.